# How should I make a realistic cucumber?

Tags: texturing, materials

I am making a 3d burger in Blender 2.92 and I don't know how to give the tomatoes and cucumbers in it a texture like in the real world.

For the cucumbers I gave a cube a subdiv modifier and then duplicated it. For the tomatoes I scaled two more duplicates. In the real world, These vegetables have a texture. I don't know where to find those textures or how to create them.

*Edit:* I actually only gave the vegetables a red and green colour, thats it. I want the vegetables to have these kind of textures.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most of the information needed is already on this site.
Just to make your job a bit easier, here is how to make a cucumber slice.

1. Add a cylinder
2. Find a [photo of a cucumber slice](https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/122-1226972_cucumbers-png-image-transparent-background-cucumber-slice-png.png) and a [photo of a cucumber peel](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_kwzYBTXYR4Q/Sr7uj_HOtII/AAAAAAAAA2s/XFjIu9kz_9s/s640/cucumber_unwrap+1k.jpg)
3. Create and assign two materials ([Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/516/78972))

Done.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought we had to do it ike this but I asked to make sure. Now it looks like a real cucumber slice.

Comment: No problem, have fun with your project :)